# モデルビュー行列からの要素抽出

Tags: opengl, 行列

MVP行列から元の各要素を抽出し、OpenGLにおける風景の再現を試みています。

そのままMVPをシェーダーに与えれば、同じ風景を描画することはできますが、
客観的に視点を表現するために、上記のようなロジックが必要になりました。

現在、4x4のMVP行列を元に、
　・カメラ位置
　・カメラ姿勢
を計算しようとしているのですが、モデル行列のスケールなどがどのように行列に影響しているのかが抽出できず、難航しております。

うまく抽出する方法はあるのでしょうか？もしくは、非可逆のためそもそも完全抽出はできないのでしょうか？
射影行列は既知ですが、その他の情報はありません。

ご助力のほど宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: "MVP行列"=(Model行列×View行列×Projection行列) を意味していますか？"抽出"がView行列の復元を意図しているなら、MVPとPだけからVの復元は数式上非可逆だと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。上記、その通りです。説明不足で申し訳ございません。数式上非可逆とのこと、ありがとうございました。この場合、例えばカメラ位置だけなど、制限した情報の抽出も不可になるのでしょうか？